# getTransaction returns null for old transactions

Tags: go-ethereum

Fully synced node returns `null` for old transactions when queried using `getTransaction` or `getTransactionReceipt`.

Using `getTransactionFromBlock(blockNumber, txIndex)` however will return the transaction.

Any idea why this happens and how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from `geth 1.10`, node will not index old transactions and unindex existing old ones as new blocks pile on.

That's configured in the `--txlookuplimit value` option, as explained in [docs](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options):

> Number of recent blocks to maintain transactions index for (default = about one year, 0 = entire chain) (default: 2350000)

You can change an existing node load parameters and add `--txlookuplimit=0`, it'll then index all transactions since genesis.