# All Transactions from Genesis

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blocks

I need all transactions from genesis block, I dont care about replaying account states. I try fast mode sync and I am able to get transactions under each block in recent blocks. But when I try to get transactions under blocks 0 to 1000000 (essentially initial blocks), I get no transaction hashes under those blocks. I know archive node is an overkill for me - how to get all transactions from each block from block 0 in least resource consuming way?

Comment: A similar question was asked recently https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102945/gettransaction-returns-null-for-old-transactions, can you check if the answer also applies to your case?

Comment: thanks, lets see, I give it a try now